# Convergence in Real Analysis vs Improper Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

In these days I'm studying about real analysis and Improper Riemann integral. And my problem is mainly based on series and sequences on above sections. If we mainly consider about a function like  f(x) = $\frac{1}{n^p} $ in both sections like,

- In Integration, $\rhd$ $\int_0^\infty \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$

  In Real Analysis, $\rhd$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\!f(x)$

So in here my lecturer got the convergence of above sequences different in each particular sections in this way,
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{In Real Analysis} & \text{In Improper Riemann Integral} \\ \hline
\text{When  p > 1} & converge & diverge \\ \hline
\text{When 1 $\geq$ p > 0} & diverge & converge \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Can anyone please explain why the convergence is happening totally different in these sections ?

And my other question is  above peculiar condition is not valid for tests in each particular sections like limit comparison test, Direct comparison test, absolute convergence. 
Although f(x) changing was different we consider same conditions for above tests in real analysis and Improper Riemann integral.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm guessing you meant $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^p}$. But wherever you got this table, it's completely incorrect. $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\,dx=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^p}\,dx$ diverges for all values of $p\in\Bbb{R}$. If you modify the limits of integration $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^p}\,dx$, then this converges if and only if $1<p<\infty$. On the other hand $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^p}$ converges if and only if $p<1$. Also, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}$ converges if and only if $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^p}\,dx$ converges which happens if and only if $1<p<\infty$.